# Probablity of matching the pair correctly

Tags: probability

There are four pairs of clothes i.e a pant and a shirt of the same brand but of different sizes (s,m,l,xl). A worker randomly puts one pant and one shirt into the boxes without noticing the size. What is the probablity that he gets each pair correctly sorted into their size?

I assigned P Q R S to be the boxes and p1 p2 q1 q2 r1 r2 s1 s2 as the names for the individual shirts and pants respectively.

P(all pairs correct)= P(p1)*P(p2)......*P(s2)
P(all pairs correct)= 1/8 * 1/7 * 1/6 *......*1 = 1/256.

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: It's the same as if there're already shirts in the boxes, and he only throws the pants. In that case, each random throw corresponds to a permutation. Only one permutation is correct, therefore your probability is 1/4!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assuming there's $\frac{1}{8}$ chance of putting the 'p' shirt into the 'P' box. But in reality, you want  $\frac{1}{4}$  because if you're choosing a shirt, you won't be considering the pants. Similarly, the probability of the 'p' pants going into the 'P' box will be $\frac{1}{4}$ and not $\frac{1}{7}$. For the next box, you have  $\frac{1}{3}$ for each. The next box is $\frac{1}{2}$ and the final box is $\frac{1}{1}$. So using your method you get:

$$P(\text{all pairs correct}) = \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\left(\frac{1}{1}\right)^2 = 
\left(\frac{1}{4!}\right)^2$$

But this still isn't correct, because you didn't take into account the fact that the boxes can be in any order. Right now you're only calculating the probability they're all matched given that single box order. There are 4! possible box orders, so multiply the answer above by 4! to get your final answer.

As a side note, a much easier way of doing this problem is as follows:

Assume you have 4 boxes laid out and you toss a shirt into each one (doesn't matter which one goes where). There are 4! ways you can put your pants into the boxes with the shirts in them. Only one of these 4! ways will pair everything correctly. So the probability of randomly pairing them correctly is $\frac{1}{4!}$, same as above.